# Python flask - redirect to same page with query results

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've gone through a number of other answers, but can't work out how they relate to my issue.  I'm relatively new to Python and Flask, but keen to learn.

Context is that I'm adding a father and / or mother on my home page (in any order) and redirecting to the /family/ page.  Once I have that page displayed, I can add the other parent and then proceed to add the children. I can add as many children as I need, and every time I add a child's name, I want it to display in a list, with a blank pair of fields and an add button appearing after I add each child (ready for the next child).  Most of this works fine BUT I'm trying to protect against the last child forename / surname I submitted being resubmitted when I refresh the page.

Here's part of my Python code:

```
@app.route("/family/<parentsid>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_family(parentsid):

    form = AddIndividual()

    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.form.get("addfather") == "Add":
            add_father(form)

            return redirect(url_for("show_family", parentsid=session["partners.id"]))

        if request.form.get("addmother") == "Add":
            add_mother(form)

            return redirect(url_for("show_family", parentsid=session["partners.id"]))

        if request.form.get("addchild") == "Add":
            child_forenames = form.child_forenames.data
            child_surname = form.child_surname.data
            child_fullname = fullname(child_forenames, child_surname)

            new_child = Individual(child_surname, child_fullname, child_forenames)
            db.session.add(new_child)

            db.session.commit()
            db.session.flush()

            session["child.id"] = new_child.id

            link_child(individual_id=session["child.id"], parents_id=session["partners.id"])

            childlist = db.session.query(Individual.fullname).join(FamilyLink).filter(Parents.id == parentsid).all()
            children = [c[0] for c in childlist]

            session["children"] = children

            form.child_forenames.data = ""

            return render_template("home.html", form=form, father_fullname=father_fullname,
                                   mother_fullname=mother_fullname, children=children) # This is probably the problem!

            # return redirect(url_for("show_family", parentsid=session["partners.id"]))  This is the other line I've tried (see below)

    return render_template("home.html", form=form, father_fullname=father_fullname, mother_fullname=mother_fullname)
```

The relevant part of the HTML template is:

```
            <form method="POST" class="col-md-12">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6">
                            <h4>Children</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6">
                            {% if children %}
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                {% for child in children %}
                                <li class="list-group-item"><h3>{{ child }}</h3></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                            <br>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="input-group">
                                {{ form.child_forenames() }}
                                {{ form.child_surname() }}
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" name="addchild"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

From other answers, I'm sure the answer is to use redirect rather than render_template and potentially something around using GET (as well as the POST I need to submit the data from the form).

If I use `return redirect(url_for("show_family", parentsid=session["partners.id"]))` instead of  `render_template` , the form doesn't resubmit anything which is great, but it doesn't show the children list at all (even though it saves the data fine).

Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect does a `get` on the page. It uses the render_template in the last line of our function. You do not pass the children there, so the page will not show them.